# Magento 2.1.9 - Frontend Account Address book modification

Tags: magento2, customer, frontend, magento-community, magento-2.1.9

So I want to add some text under "Additional address entries":

[image]

I tried overriding `\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\address\book.phtml` in my custom theme `\Magento_Customer\templates\address\book.phtml` like this:

```
<div class="block block-addresses-list">
<div class="block-title"><strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Additional Address Entries')) ?></strong></div>
<div class="block-content">
    <?php if ($_pAddsses = $block->getAdditionalAddresses()): ?>
        <ol class="items addresses">
            <?php foreach ($_pAddsses as $_address): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <address>
                        <?php echo $block->getAddressHtml($_address) ?><br />
                    </address>
                    <div class="item actions">
                        <a class="action edit" href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('customer/address/edit', ['id' => $_address->getId()])) ?>"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Edit Address')) ?></span></a>
                        <a class="action delete" href="#" role="delete-address" data-address="<?php echo $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper::class)->escapeHtmlAttr($_address->getId()) ?>"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Delete Address')) ?></span></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="empty"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('You have no other address entries in your address book.')) ?></p>
    <?php endif ?>
<!-- My added code -->
    <p class="empty"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('You must get in contact with your representative in order to do any modification to your personal details.')) ?></p>
</div>
```

It doesn't appear to have any changes, but not only what I have changed but also if I try to put some `die('text')` in order to make sure I'm working in the right place.

Of course I run the commands:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Make sure file path is fine or not. According to the mentioned path everything looks ok. Can you write the full path of book.phtml in your theme?

Comment: As far as I understand the custom_theme folders are like "smart enough" to find the path missing. I have lots of other modifications that are like that and work perfectly. I really don't know what I have missing.

Comment: Did you try to modify the same in vendor? Just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what happened, it appears we had a extension called `CustomerCrm` that overrides the theme:

```
app\code\Gsp\CustomerCrm\view\frontend\templates\address\book.phtml
```

In the end I had to modify the CustomerCrm Extension, the same file and just put the same change in the design.